# Php array verificar se existe valores ou chaves

Tags: php, html, array

```
[TotalPed] => Array
    (
        [VlrTotalIPI] => 0.00
        [VlrTotalItens] => 652.68
        [VlrTotalDesc] => 0.00
        [VlrTotalPed] => 652.68
        [PercComPed] => 0.00
        [PercComPed2] => 0.00
        [VlrFrete] => 0.00
        [TotalBaseIcms] => 0.00
        [VlrTotalIcms] => 0.00
        [VlrTotalBaseIcmST] => 0.00
        [VlrTotalIcmST] => 0.00
        [vFCPUFDestTot] => 0.00
        [vICMSUFDestTot] => 0.00
        [vICMSUFRemetTot] => 0.00
    )
```

Tenho este array em uma váriavel **$meuArray**. Gostária de saber como faço para verificar se os campos existem (keys).

Exemplo: `[VlrTotalIPI]` caso não exista falar que necessita deste campo (**Acredito que tenha que comparar com um array onde estão só os campos necessários**).

E também se existem valores para essas chaves, novamente caso não exista, apontar a chave que necessita de valor. Usando função claro, para fazer isso independente do Array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se vc precisa checar separadamente pode usar [array_key_exists()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-key-exists.php), ou [isset()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php) para o nome da chave, e [empty()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php) para o valor.

```
if( array_key_exists( 'VirTotalPI', $meuArray ) ) {
    // chave existe
   if( ! empty( $meuArray['VirTotalPI'] ) {
       // não está vazio
   }
}
```

Se puder ser tudo junto, `empty()` resolve tudo sozinho (retorna verdadeiro se não existe ou se está vazio)